# How do I store a password in such a way that I can obtain the plain-text password again?

Tags: encryption, password, hashing, api

Consider the following scenario:

My app is utilizing a third-party API which requires a username and password for authentication. Unlike most APIs, which have one username and password set for the developer to make calls, this API has a unique username and password pair for each customer. Thus, each customer using my app will need to input their username and password for their account on this other service, into my app. I then need to store this data in my own database, as I will need to call the third-party API on my customer's behalf repeatedly without asking them for their credentials over and over. (Several well-known apps use this model, such as the fintech company Plaid.)

I know that the de-facto standard for storing passwords in a database is by using a one-way hashing algorithm. However, in my case, I can't see how this would work, as I need to present a plain-text password to the third-party API, and cannot do so if I've only stored hashed information.

I've had trouble finding clear or trusted guidance about how to proceed in this situation. I'm open to the idea that there are other avenues with this scenario I haven't considered. How can I store the passwords in a secure way (if someone got access to my database, they couldn't get their hands on plain text passwords) in this situation?

Comment: Opinion-based question... You'd store encrypted login/password, of course. The best way is to use asymmetric encryption using pass+salt or certificate. The decryption procedure should not be available for viewing/modification/external call. It can also be compiled function or  separate process.

Comment: "*Several well-known apps use this model, such as the fintech company Plaid*" - I believe you're probably misinterpreting how these apps work. It's highly doubtful they are storing user passwords in an insecure way, as you're interested in. There are ways to keep a password in Memory temporarily, in a *secure* way, not as plaintext, depending on the programming language you're using (e.g. "secure string" is a concept in some languages). But I'd assume even that methodology is not perfect, and there's probably an alternative implementation that can utilize this 3rd party service in a safer way.

Comment: @J.D. "*...storing user passwords in an insecure way, as you're interested in*" - I feel that this statement misconstrues my words. I **do** want to store passwords in a secure way, only, in a manner in which I can give the password to an API at a later time.

Comment: @JCollier giving the password at any time means it is not just in memory. It must be written somewhere (possibly in an encrypted form).

Comment: @JCollier My intentions aren't to misconstrue your words, rather just calling out the question "*How do I store a password in such a way that I can **obtain the plain-text password** again?*" for being an insecure ask. No app should ever be able to obtain someone's password in plaintext.

Comment: The ability to decrypt a password to its original plain text is insecure by definition. **No one does this.** If an API will only accept the plaintext password then the only *secure* way to handle this is to let the API prompt your users for that password every time, and not store it anywhere in your application.